# Kotlin simple generic function compile error (*)

Tags: kotlin

I make a simple function sqr, but it's not working, what's wrong ?

```
fun <T : Number> sqr(value: T): T {    
    return value * value
}

fun main() {
    print("${sqr(5)}")    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Number` is an abstraction over `Double`, `Int` etc. but it doesn't include any common behavior. Rather, it contains functionality for converting between the different concrete types.

See the source [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Number.kt) (or press "Go to implementation" in the IDE)

You'd have to convert them to a concrete subclass in order to get it to compile:

```
fun <T : Number> sqr(value: T): T {    
    return value.toInt() * value.toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `times` function (which the `*` operator is translated to) for `Number`.

`Number` is just the abstract super class of `Int`, `Float`, `Double` etc. and only contains abstract conversion functions: `toInt()`, `toFloat()`, `toDouble()` etc.

So, how to get around that and have a `sqrt` function for all of them?

Since there is no super type for them which includes the basic operations, the best idea would be most likely to just have a separate implementation for each type and not use generic types.

```
fun sqr(value: Int) = value * value
fun sqr(value: Float) = value * value
fun sqr(value: Double) = value * value
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could have an operator extension on Number, taking advantage of kotlin smartcasts; which could look something like this:

```
operator fun Number.times(value: Number): Number {
   return when(this) {
        is Int -> this * value.toInt()
        is Double -> this * value.toDouble()
        is Short -> this * value.toShort()
        is Float -> this * value.toFloat()
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Value is not a number")
    }
}
```

So your square function would be:

```
fun sqr(value: Number): Number {
    return value * value
}
```

I suppose the benefit here is that you maintain only 1 square function, and an operator with a number of cases that represent which concrete number classes you wish to support.